# Checking whether the input is a whole number

Tags: c, fflush

I need to make a function that gets input from the user and makes sure that it is a whole number and does not contain any character.

I wrote this code which works perfectly for integers and for single characters. But it terminates if I enter `dfd` i.e. multiple character input. Below is my code compiled with gcc on Linux:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int getint()
{
    int input = 0;
    int a;
    int b, i = 0;
    while((a = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if (a<'0'||a>'9')
        {
            printf("\nError in input!Please try entering a whole number again:");
            input=0;
            fflush(stdin);
            return getint();
        }
        b = a - '0';
        input = ((input*10) + b);
        i++;
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: friend learn [indentation](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/indent_c.html).

Comment: Why are you doing fflush on stdin?  It is an output function (unless I am about to learn something really obscure).  Did you mean fpurge?

Comment: The behavior of `fflush(stdin)` is not defined by the C standard. It is defined by some implementations, and by POSIX, but it's not useful here. What you probably want to do is read and discard input characters until you see either `'\n'` or `EOF`.

Comment: And recursion is an odd choice.

Comment: `int a; while ((a = getchar()) != '\n' && a != EOF) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that calling fflush(stdin) is undefined.  fflush is for flushing an output stream, not an input stream.  Try replacing it with another way to clear the remaining input buffer, like `while (getchar() != '\n');` and see if that resolves the issue. (you should probably do something more robust like also catching EOF so you're not in an infinite loop)

Comment: Thanks..Worked like a charm! This was the easiest way to clear the input buffer. Just in case is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `fflush` on an input stream invokes undefined behaviour. Even if your implementation defines it for input streams, it's not portable. There is no standard way to flush an input stream. Therefore, the `fflush(stdin);` is not correct. You should read the characters and discard them till and including the newline in the `stdin` buffer. I suggest the following change to your function.

```
int getint(void) {
    int input = 0;
    int a;

    while((a = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (a < '0' || a > '9') {
            printf("Error in input!Please try entering a whole number again:\n");
            input = 0;

            // read and discard characters in the stdin buffer up till
            // and including the newline
            while((a = getchar()) != '\n'); // the null statement
            return getint();  // recursive call
        }
        input = (input * 10) + (a - '0');
    }
    return input;
}
```

Also, please read this C FAQ - [If fflush won't work, what can I use to flush input?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `fflush` to `fpurge` caused your program to start working for me.

Comment: `fpurge` is non-standard and non-portable. And quoting its man page: "Usually it is a mistake to want to discard input buffers."

Comment: fpurge isnt included in stdio.h Where do i find it?